# I seem to be getting this error on custom keyboard extension, without making any changes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to get the log output of the custom keyboard, however from the main app, it does not show it to me. so if I change from main app to keyboard, and then run that, 8/10 from the vanilla built in Xcode implementation I get the following error when it launches:

P.S. is there a way to get the logs to output BOTH the main app, and the extension (e.g. print statements from extension)?

```
dyld`gdb_image_notifier:
->  0x10014fec8 <+0>:   stp    x20, x19, [sp, #-32]!
    0x10014fecc <+4>:   stp    x29, x30, [sp, #16]
    0x10014fed0 <+8>:   add    x29, sp, #16              ; =16 
    0x10014fed4 <+12>:  sub    sp, sp, #16               ; =16 
    0x10014fed8 <+16>:  mov    x8, x2
    0x10014fedc <+20>:  mov    x9, x1
    0x10014fee0 <+24>:  adrp   x19, 38
    0x10014fee4 <+28>:  add    x19, x19, #2024           ; =2024 
    0x10014fee8 <+32>:  ldr    x19, [x19]
    0x10014feec <+36>:  stur   x19, [x29, #-24]
    0x10014fef0 <+40>:  mov    w1, w9
    0x10014fef4 <+44>:  mov    x10, sp
    0x10014fef8 <+48>:  lsl    x11, x1, #3
    0x10014fefc <+52>:  add    x11, x11, #15             ; =15 
    0x10014ff00 <+56>:  and    x11, x11, #0xffffffff0
    0x10014ff04 <+60>:  sub    x2, x10, x11
    0x10014ff08 <+64>:  mov    sp, x2
    0x10014ff0c <+68>:  cbz    w9, 0x10014ff24           ; <+92>
    0x10014ff10 <+72>:  mov    x10, x2
    0x10014ff14 <+76>:  ldr    x11, [x8], #24
    0x10014ff18 <+80>:  str    x11, [x10], #8
    0x10014ff1c <+84>:  sub    w9, w9, #1                ; =1 
    0x10014ff20 <+88>:  cbnz   w9, 0x10014ff14           ; <+76>
    0x10014ff24 <+92>:  cbz    w0, 0x10014ff38           ; <+112>
    0x10014ff28 <+96>:  cmp    w0, #1                    ; =1 
    0x10014ff2c <+100>: b.ne   0x10014ff40               ; <+120>
    0x10014ff30 <+104>: orr    w0, wzr, #0x1
    0x10014ff34 <+108>: b      0x10014ff3c               ; <+116>
    0x10014ff38 <+112>: movz   w0, #0
    0x10014ff3c <+116>: bl     0x10015035c               ; _dyld_debugger_notification
    0x10014ff40 <+120>: ldur   x8, [x29, #-24]
    0x10014ff44 <+124>: sub    x8, x19, x8
    0x10014ff48 <+128>: cbnz   x8, 0x10014ff5c           ; <+148>
    0x10014ff4c <+132>: sub    sp, x29, #16              ; =16 
    0x10014ff50 <+136>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #16]
    0x10014ff54 <+140>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp], #32
    0x10014ff58 <+144>: ret    
    0x10014ff5c <+148>: bl     0x100150234               ; __stack_chk_fail
```